# How to cache dynamic results

Tags: php, mysql, rest, caching

My API gets activities from a database based on a dynamic set of query parameters:

- the bounds of a google map;
- the center of the map (to calculate distance);
- keywords;
- start / end dates
- ...

Now how can one cache results that will continuously be different?
Map bounds are sent as query parameters and will never be the same for subsequent requests.

How can I make sure that my server doesn't get overloaded?
I cannot believe that an application is doomed not to have the ability to be optimised.

Comment: if results "*will  continuously be different*" then caching is pointless

Comment: sorry, the logic bamboozles me